# Divs in row - one's height set by content, the other's set to match

Tags: html, css

This feels like a really really simple problem, but I'm struggling here.

I have looked at a number of other questions (eg: [Child divs next to each other with auto height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073801/child-divs-next-to-each-other-with-auto-height), [How do I keep two side-by-side divs the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-divs-the-same-height)), and haven't found a solution.

I have two divs, in a wrapping div, displayed side by side. The height of one is determined by text content of indeterminate length, and the height of the other (which just has a background image) should match.

My thinking was something like this:

```css
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .image {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600);
      height: 100%; /* Shows up w no height! */
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      /* Needed to make the image show */
      /* height: 200px; */
    }
    
    .content {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px; /* Height is sum of text height and padding */
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>This could go on and on and on, and should determine the height of the set of divs, sitting next to each other. I do NOT want to program a set height, because that could clip long text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does the height need to match dynamically or you can set a fixed height and then scroll on text?

Comment: The former. Scrolling won't work, though if this is undoable (!?), then I'd probably constrain text length or resize text programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/how-can-i-make-flexbox-children-100-height-of-their-parent) you should remove your `height` property and set `align-items:stretch` on your wrapper (but it happens to be the default, so just remove the height and it will work).

```css
.wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      border: 1px solid black;
      align-items: stretch;
    }
    
    .image {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600);
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      /* Needed to make the image show */
      /* height: 200px; */
    }
    
    .content {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px; /* Height is sum of text height and padding */
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>This could go on and on and on, and should determine the height of the set of divs, sitting next to each other. I do NOT want to program a set height, because that could clip long text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I had no idea of this behaviour, I'll quote the comment in that question that was the most helpful.

> Yep, Chrome has some issues, especially with nested flexboxes. For example I've got a nested flex box with children that have height:100% but they are rendering with natural height instead. And the weird thing is if I change their height to auto, then they render as height:100% like I was trying to do. It is definitely not intuitive if that's how it should work. – trusktr

Comment: How weird. Would never occur to me to remove the height value rather than set it to 100% or auto.